# Excel - VBA macro and if

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, messagebox

I'm new in VBA and I am trying to do simply macro. I need my macro to work like this:

1. If there is a value in E5 cell, which is greater than 1, show a message box with text like "Your value is" /get value from E5/
2. I want to repeat this condition for all cells in column E.

First, I started with something that would work:

```
Sub test()
    If Range("E5").Value > "1" Then
        MsgBox "Your value is" (here I don't know how to import real value from E5)
    End If
End Sub
```

And then I can click "Run" and the macro works ok (it means "formally ok", because this is not the target effect yet). But this macro only works when I click "Run" and I would like it to work always, even when I turn Excel off and turn it on again. Assigning a macro to an auto-shape is much easier, but here I fell :(

Answer (score 0):

Note that `"1"` is a text/string and not a number. So if you want to compare a numeric value with `>` or `<` you need to write

```
If Range("E5").Value > 1 Then
```

or you don't get the result you want.

To get the value into your message box you need to concatenate it to your text using the `&` sign.

```
MsgBox "Your value is " & Range("E5").Value
```

To do this for all cells in Column E you need to loop

```
Dim LastRow As Long 'find last used row in E
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

Dim iRow As Long
For iRow = 1 To LastRow
    If Cells(iRow, "E").Value > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Your value in Cell E" & iRow & " is " & Cells(iRow, "E").Value
    End If
Next iRow
```

But note that if you have many values that are `>1` in E then you will get many message boxes. If you only want to show the first message box that is `>1` then put a `Exit For` right below `MsgBow`. This will then cancel the validation after the first invalid value was found and reported.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion works fine:) I am still analyzing the loop mechanism, because it is new to me here. But I still have trouble running the macro outside of the development area. The only way at the moment is to click "Run macro" to see its work. However, I would like the macro to work automatically depending on the change in the indicated cell, without my participation. How to do that?:c

Comment: If you don't have formulas in column E then either use the `Worksheet_Change` event for that, or much easier without VBA check out how to [Apply data validation to cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249). I would recommend the data validation.